# Using robocopy instead of xcopy in batch file loop

Tags: loops, batch-file

I've got a batch file I've been using to track down all the files in a directory (and its subfolders) that contain a list of around 15 product numbers, entered as a space-separated list. (For example, "54323 12345 68483 234 9993384 29944".)

However, I'm basically having it search through a massive image pool twice per product. Since I usually have a list of about 15 products to pull images for, that can take a while, since it has to search the whole folder 30 times. (Files are either named 12345.jpg or 12345_n.jpg.)

Is there a way to use Robocopy (or something else) to speed things up?

Here's my batch file right now:

```
set SourceFolder=\\ImagePoolNetworkLocation
set TargetFolder=C:\Users\BevansDesign\Desktop\Images
set /p SKUList=SKU Numbers:
for %%i in (%SKUList%) do (
    xcopy /s %SourceFolder%\%%i.* %TargetFolder%\
    xcopy /s %SourceFolder%\%%i_*.* %TargetFolder%\
)
```

I was thinking that if I can enter the loop into the robocopy command itself, I could have it look for *all* the files in the first search. This is basically the logic chain (I think) but I don't know how to insert the "for" function into the robocopy call.

```
robocopy /s %SourceFolder%\ %TargetFolder%\ [for %%i in (%SKUList%) do (%%i.* and %%i_*.*)]
```

Is this possible? I'm pretty bad at basic programming stuff like this.

Thanks for the help, or even just pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: If you use `xcopy /s %SourceFolder%\%%i*.jpg %TargetFolder%\ ` then it will copy all matching files in one pass, both `12345.jpg` and `12345_anything.jpg` - is there a problem with doing that?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that. Unfortunately, there are also files with names like 123456.jpg that I don't want to get. So I need to be able to get 12345.jpg, 12345_1.jpg, but not 123456.jpg. :(

Answer (score 0):

This filters the entire skulist using `DIR` and `findstr` in one pass:

At the moment the `ECHO` command will only display all the `xcopy` commands in a list for you to check if it's using the correct syntax, and you can remove the `ECHO` if it all looks right.

It will copy all the files into one directory `%TargetFolder%` so let me know if they need to be copied into individual folders under %TargetFolder%.

```
@echo off
set "SourceFolder=\\ImagePoolNetworkLocation"
set "TargetFolder=C:\Users\BevansDesign\Desktop\Images"
set /p SKUList=SKU Numbers:
set list=
for %%a in (%SKUList%) do call set list=%%list%% %%a.jpg %%a_*.jpg
pushd "%SourceFolder%"
for /f "delims=" %%i in (' dir %list% /b /s /a-d ^|findstr /ir "%list%" ') do (
    ECHO xcopy "%%i" "%TargetFolder%\"
)
popd
pause
```

Comment: Test this to see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up just changing the command in the loop to:

```
robocopy /s %SourceFolder%\ %TargetFolder%\ %%i.* %%i_*.*
```

That *would* theoretically cut the time in half, but it seems that Robocopy is MUCH faster than XCopy (at least for this use), so it took way less time. Good enough for me!